# I have an array and I want to pass it into a function then modify it from the function, how can i do that?

Tags: c

Example

```
//This is my function
void myfunc (how does the definition look like?)
{
int counter = 0;
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
{
*arr[counter] += 10;
}

int main(void)
{
char arr[100] = {'\0'};
myfunc (how does this look like?)
return 0;
}
```

I want to pass in something like a pointer so I can modify it directly from the `myfunc()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an array is passed to a function, a pointer to the first element is passed.

```
void myfunc(char *arr) {
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
        arr[counter] += 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void myfunc (char *s)
```

and in `main` function, call as

```
myfunc (arr);
```

Comment: @tjjjjjj; That's because you are dereferencing an array element. `*arr[counter] += 10;` should be `arr[counter] += 10;`.

Answer (score 0):

C is not a object oriented language. You have to pass in the size of the array so you will be able to iterate on it safely.

```
void myfunc (char * arr, int size)
{
   int counter = 0;
   for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
   {
      arr[counter] += 10;
   }
}

int main()
{
   char arr[100] = {'\0'};
   myfunc (arr, 100);
   return 0;
}
```